# How can I use WordPress ajax to set a cookie and redirect before a page loads

Tags: ajax, wordpress, redirect, caching, cookies

I’m working on a WordPress site requirement to redirect a user when they’re in a certain country to their country specific homepage.

*(I’ve had to do this via WP Ajax because full page caching prevents it working directly on live hosting environment - I was previously doing it quite simply in functions.php hooked into 'init').*

This works when I call it at the start of the header template, but only after the current page content is shown. It would be great if I could hook it in to happen before the page is displayed e.g. like using hooks such as: 'wp_loaded', ‘template_redirect’ but jQuery needs to be available...

Here is my code. It needs tidying some more but appreciate any suggestions as how to make a redirect happen before page contents displayed?

```
function invoke_county_redirection() {
              
    ob_start();
    ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_url = "<?= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
        jQuery.post(ajax_url, {
            'action': 'country_redirection',
        }, function (response) {
            // Set the cookie to say we're performing the redirect - this will flag it not to happen again
            createCookie('redirected', 'true');
            if (response != '') {
                window.location.replace(response);
            }
    
        function createCookie(name, value, days) {
            var expires = "";
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
       echo ob_get_clean();
       return;
    }
    
    function country_redirection() {
    
        $redirect_url = '';
     
        if ( $_COOKIE['redirected'] !== 'true' ) {
            
            /* declare empty result url */
            $result['url'] = '';
    
            /* Call on geoip plugin to get the country from their IP address */
            $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
            $country_code = $userInfo->country->isoCode;
    
            /* if we've retreived the country code for the current user */
            if ( $country_code ) {
                /* GET THE CORRECT REDIRECT URL IF APPLICABLE TO THE USER COUNTRY */
                $redirect_url = get_country_url($country_code);        
            }
        }
        echo $redirect_url;
        wp_die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_country_redirection', 'country_redirection' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_country_redirection', 'country_redirection' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update in case anyone else can be helped by this.

I hooked the hooked the function invoke_county_redirection() into the **wp_head** hook as follows...

```
add_action('wp_head', "invoke_county_redirection");
```

This means that jQuery would be loaded and the country detect/redirect process runs.

However, it doesn't make the request syncronous and in this particular scenario with wanting to redirect before the page loads, I have given up on this. There is a minefield of issues trying to get around full page caching trying to store a cookie and do a redirect before the page loads. I should have just insisted that caching remained off where this needs to run, so this is our conclusion. We are instead optimsing the site as best we can with GTMetrix and loader.io and we will cross the bridge of scalability as and when we need to.